# Exporting variables with eval not working as expected

Tags: bash, environment-variables

I've got a file with variable exports like this:

```
$ cat file.txt
export A=foo
export B=\"B-\$A\" # I want export another var, which depends on a previously exported var
```

Using `eval` to execute those statements does not produce the expected behavior:

```
$ eval $(cat file.txt)
$ echo ${B:-unset}
unset
```

When not using `export`, it works as expected:

```
$ eval $(echo "A=foo B=\"B-\$A\"")
$ echo ${B:-unset}
B-foo
```

Why the difference, and is there any way to achieve the same result without removing the `export` from the variable `A` (that part of the file comes from an external source outside my control, but I can change  the variable B)?

Comment: Isn't the difference that your `file.txt` version has backslashes before the `"` and `$`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, change `file.txt` to this (and consider naming it `file.sh` instead):

```
export A=foo
export B="B-$A"
```

Then, instead of `eval $(cat file.txt)`, do this:

```
source file.txt
```

That does the same thing as if you had pasted the content `file.txt` into your shell.